# Existence of an a.e. orientation preserving isometry implies isometric immersibility?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, isometry

Let $M,N$ be smooth, connected, **oriented** $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds (perhaps with boundary).

Suppose there exist a map $f:M \to N$ which is differentiable almost everywhere on $M$, and its differential is an *orientation-preserving isometry* almost everywhere.

> Is it true that $M$ can be isometrically immersed in $N$? (i.e does there exist a *smooth* isometric immersion $M \to N$?)

---

If we omit the requirement of *orientation-preserving*, then this is false:

Gromov showed that for any metric $g$ on the unit $d$-dimensional disk $\mathbb{D}^d$ there is an arcwise isometry $f:(\mathbb{D}^d,g) \to (\mathbb{R}^d,e)$ (which has to be an [isometry a.e](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257165/there-is-no-arcwise-isometry-from-a-high-dimensional-manifold-into-a-low-dimensi)).

If $g$ is non-flat, then no smooth isometric immersion exist, of course.

**Note:** In that case, Gromov's arcwise isometry $f$ cannot preserve orientation: It is $1$-Lipschitz, and hence in $W^{1,\infty}(M,N)$. 
 My colleagues and I showed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08892v1.pdf) (section 3) that any weakly differentiable map $f \in W^{1,\infty}(M,N)$ satisfying $df \in SO(n)$ a.e is weakly harmonic, hence smooth. (This shows $f$ cannot be orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing on any open subset of the domain. It must "switch" rotations infinitely often).

**Edit:** It [turns out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2176520/104576) $M$ is not necessarily isometrically immersible in $N$. However, in the example given $M,N$ were both flat.

This still leaves open the question whether examples of such maps exist for pairs of maniolds which have *different* curvatures.

> Specifically, is there an example for a non-flat $M$, and a flat $N$, such that there exist an a.e orientation-preserving isometric immersion $M \to N$?

The point is to see how much flexibility this notion allows. Gromov's maps show that curvature differences between manifolds do not obstruct existence of a.e isometries.

**Do such differences obstruct a.e-*orientation-preserving* isometries?**

---

Note that in general an "almost everywhere isometry" does not need to be smooth.

An example is $M=[0,1],N=[0,2],f(x)=c(x)+x$ where $c$ is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). In this case, $f'=1$ a.e, and $M$ can be isometrically immersed in $N$, via the natural inclusion map.

To refute the claim, one could try to use $f^{-1}:[0,2] \to [0,1]$, but it is not differentiable a.e on $[0,2]$;

$f ^{-1}$ is differentiable on $f(O)$, when $O$ is the complement of the Cantor set (since $O$ is the set where $f$ is differentiable). By the definition of $f$, it is not hard to see that $m(f(O))=m(O)=1$, hence is **not** of full measure in $[0,2]$.

Comment: Hint: Use your example of function $f$ to construct a homeomorphism from the circle $M$ of length $1$ to the circle $N$ of length $2$, which is an isometric immersion a.e.. But, of course, there is no smooth isometric immersion $M\to N$.

Comment: Thanks! Your idea is very nice. (In afterthought, it looks very natural to use the example I gave to "wrap" one circle onto the other). I must say I am still interested in finding examples in higher dimensions, though. (I would be happy to see examples when the curvatures of $M,N$ differ, which is impossible in dimension $1$, since everything is flat there. I think your idea, to use this "seed example" as a way to "pathologically double" a manifold, can probably be lifted to two dimensional examples.

Comment: However, I think it only naturally extends itself to cases when $M$ is a scaled version of $N$ (indeed, a double), so the signs of the curvatures would be identical. Again, I think it is interesting to see how much flexibility this notion allows. Gromov's maps show curvature differences do not obstruct a.e isometries. Do such differences obstruct a.e-orientation-preserving isometries? (e.g can we have $M$ non-flat and $N$ flat or vice versa?)

Comment: The example generalizes naturally to a map between $n$-dimensional tori or, more generally, manifolds containing flat pieces. However, the case of maps between manifolds of negative curvature looks challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on a comment by Moishe Cohen.

Let $M,N$be circles with radiuses $1,2$ respectively. We define $g:M \to N$ by

$$g(e^{2\pi it})=2e^{\pi if(t)}$$

where $f(x)=x+c(x)$ is the example function given in the question.

$g$ is differentiable at $\{e^{2\pi it} \, | \,t \in [0,1]\setminus C \}$, which is a set of full measure on the unit circle $M$.

Let $ \alpha(s)=e^{2\pi i(t+s)},\alpha'(s)=2\pi i  e^{2\pi i(t+s)},\alpha'(0)=2\pi i  e^{2\pi it}$: Then

$$dg_{(e^{2\pi it})}(2\pi i  e^{2\pi it})=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}g(\alpha(s))=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} 2e^{\pi if(t+s)}=2e^{\pi if(t)}f'(t)=2e^{\pi if(t)}$$

for every $t \in [0,1]\setminus C $.

So $dg_{(e^{2\pi it})}$ maps a vector with length $2\pi$ to a vector of the same length, and since the tangent spaces are one-dimensional this implies it's an isometry a.e.

It is also easy to see it's differential is orientaion-preserving whenever it is defined.

Thus, $g$ satisfies the requirements, but $M$ is not isometrically immersible in $N$.